# internet explorer 11 block with selenium 3.4.0

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11

I've updated Selenium server to 3.4.0 and grabbed the latest `ieDriverServer.exe`. I'm using IE v11.483 on Windows 10 .

It seems, it brings up an instance of the browser and go to a webpage but unable to interact with basic elements, which works fine on FF, Edge, Chrome.

For example:

```
get http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform
click id "alert"
```

Result is :

> java.lang.AssertionError: couldnt find element id alert

And

```
get http://www.seleniumframework.com/Practiceform
send keys "sdsdf" to name "email"
```

Result is :

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with name == email (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)

Anyone else hit this issue with IE ?

Comment: Have you configured the IE browsers correctly? Look under required configurations here.  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I believe the IE browser is configured correctly...  I have run against the same setup but on another VM, and this time can click the button fine, but when doing sendKeys, one character at a time is being typed extremely slowly. That's on a VM (in azure) running IE 11.1358  on Server 2016.    Don't believe I'm behind a corporate proxy, I know IE used to work fine with my selenium setup last time I checked it about 6 six weeks ago, so assuming updates somewhere have affected this strange behaviour... including the slow typing into an input box.

Comment: @David Are you using the 64bit driver? That one usually has the issue with the slow typing and it is recommended to use the 32bit driver.

Comment: @Madis Thanks, swapping the 64bit driver to 32bit (on my azure vm) has fixed the slow sendKeys within IE.  I'll have to research further as to why my local IE won't get any further than loading a webpage.

Comment: @David usually it is caused by the ie configuration. My guess is that all the zones don't match in the ie settings. Enabled protected mode in all the zones in the security view and disable enchanced protected mode under advanced settings tab.

Comment: @David good to hear it was fixed.